# Select all check boxes and show control buttons in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I've been able to show/hide a div after checking any checkboxes. I've also been able to create a check all button that selects all of the checkboxes. The problem now is how will I  link the two together?

When I hit check all, it doesn't show/hide the div I want to show/hide but works when you select each individually. [Here is the page url](http://iambuttonbag.com/wellpledge/support.text.php)

Bonus: If anyone can also make it so that the "select all" button changes to "deselect all" Thanks, community!

The script:

```
<script>
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(
function(){
   if($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
          // if any of the checkboxes are checked then make the area visible
          $('.send-control').fadeIn(); 
   }else{
          // only if all are unchecked will this fire and hide the area
          $('.send-control').fadeOut();
   }
});

$('#toggle-all').click(function() {
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add .change() to your method:

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true).change();
```

As far as i know you have to call the change method manually because otherwise the change event wont be registered.

Comment: That's it. Thanks, now I can focus on changing the select all button to unselect.